# How to read a list from a text file in java

Tags: java, list, file

I am trying to read data from a text file which has multiple lines, for example, look the image below, it is my text file

[image]

Given a keyword from the user which is the first string in the list from the text file. I want to print the list or line corresponding to the keyword given. For example, if I am giving the keyword=59d2211ec3671594c987d008f89f043e97670a5ba6f08fe073e465116c35b440

Then I want to store [59d2211ec3671594c987d008f89f043e97670a5ba6f08fe073e465116c35b440, id4, id6, id1] as a list.

I have tried using the following function to read the text file and return the data but it's giving me some wrong input.

```
public static List<String> readLines(File file) throws Exception {
    if (!file.exists()) {
        return new ArrayList<String>();
    }
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
    List<String> results = new ArrayList<String>();
    String line = reader.readLine();
    while (line != null) {
        results.add(line);
        line = reader.readLine();
    }
    return results;
}
```

Can someone guide me through on how to implement this in a right way.

Comment: what output is it giving you?

Comment: If instead of an image you'd put the text I'd be able to test my answer before posting it

Comment: Where is "keyword" in your posted code?

Answer (score 1):

> if I am giving the keyword

Well, if you're given a value, then you should be using it

```
readLines(File file, String keyword)
```

> store as a list

Now, I assume you mean split the line into columns. If that's the case, you need to be returning at least a `List<List<String>>`

However, if not, you can do that later than collecting the lines containing the keyword like so

```
List<String> results = new ArrayList<String>();
String line = reader.readLine();
while (line != null) {
    if (line.contains(keyword))  results.add(line);
    line = reader.readLine();
}
return results;
```

FWIW, I would suggest having a look at Java 8 stream functions, including `filter`, `map`, and `toList`